# How can I run python code in Cloud Run without having to download packages everytime the code runs?

Tags: python, nltk, google-cloud-run

I am working on a basic Python Chatbot API using Flask and NLTK. Locally my code only required me to[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXc2m.png) run nltk.download('punkt') and  nltk.download('wordnet') once (Then I was able to delete the code) but within Cloud Run I have to keep those Download statements in, so with each HTTP request to my API, it redownloads those packages and causing the request to take way too long.

Is there someway for me to include these packages in the Docker Image so that they don't have to redownload or is there another alternative either within Cloud Run or Python to solve this issue?

Here is my code for reference as well as the error if I don't include the download statements from Cloud Run Logs.

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

try:
    nltk.data.find('tokenizers/punkt')
except LookupError:
    nltk.download('punkt')

try:
    nltk.data.find('tokenizers/wordnet')
except LookupError:
    nltk.download('wordnet')
```

As you can see I tried using a try except block, but with the nature of cloud run, the packages don't persistent beyond one HTTP request. Beyond that I am unsure of what else to try and I haven't found much fruitful info online pertaining to this issue.

Comment: Sure, after `pip install`, use a `RUN python -c 'import nltk; nltk.download('wordnet'); nltk.download('punkt')` in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install these into a docker image:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nltk_data

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt && python -m nltk.downloader wordnet
```

Where you should be able to find those packages downloaded at this point:

```bash
docker build -t testimage .

docker run -it testimage python
```

```py
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

nltk.data.find('tokenizers/punkt')
```